# podman tries to pull even if the image previously pulled

Tags: podman

Is it possible to force podman to run an image from the local registry?
I do podman pull gcr.io/....

podman images: shows the image I want to run

podman run : fails to pull the image from gcr.io

Why it tries to pull the image again, if it is already in the local registry?